# Failure to start tigervnc on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, vnc-server

I recently installed a minimal installation of centos 7 and have been trying to get the vncserver working with no success. I followed the guide [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/vnc-server-installation-on-centos-7) on how to install the vncserver. Everything worked until I tired to start it and then I received a segmentation fault on start up.

```
[<username>@home] ~$ vncserver :1

WARNING: The first attempt to start Xvnc failed, possibly because the font
catalog is not properly configured.  Attempting to determine an appropriate
font path for this system and restart Xvnc using that font path ...
Could not start Xvnc.


Xvnc TigerVNC 1.3.1 - built Nov 16 2016 13:38:44
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11702000, The X.Org Foundation


Sun Feb 19 21:16:55 2017
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xvnc (xorg_backtrace+0x55) [0x5bb935]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xvnc (0x400000+0x1bf7a9) [0x5bf7a9]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f9f9e6fd000+0xf370) [0x7f9f9e70c370]
(EE) 3: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9fa065e000+0x5c09) [0x7f9fa0663c09]
(EE) 4: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9fa065e000+0x836b) [0x7f9fa066636b]
(EE) 5: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9fa065e000+0x13684) [0x7f9fa0671684]
(EE) 6: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9fa065e000+0xeff4) [0x7f9fa066cff4]
(EE) 7: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9fa065e000+0x12feb) [0x7f9fa0670feb]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x7f9f9fa86000+0xfbb) [0x7f9f9fa86fbb]
(EE) 9: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9fa065e000+0xeff4) [0x7f9fa066cff4]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x7f9f9fa86000+0x15bd) [0x7f9f9fa875bd]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (dlopen+0x31) [0x7f9f9fa87051]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so (0x7f9f97229000+0x37d214) [0x7f9f975a6214]
(EE) 13: /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so (0x7f9f97229000+0x66d530) [0x7f9f97896530]
(EE) 14: /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so (0x7f9f97229000+0x968e0) [0x7f9f972bf8e0]
(EE) 15: /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so (0x7f9f97229000+0x41dbd2) [0x7f9f97646bd2]
(EE) 16: /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so (0x7f9f97229000+0x31946c) [0x7f9f9754246c]
(EE) 17: /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so (0x7f9f97229000+0x317042) [0x7f9f97540042]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/Xvnc (0x400000+0x8e420) [0x48e420]
(EE) 19: /usr/bin/Xvnc (GlxExtensionInit+0x16a) [0x48d83a]
(EE) 20: /usr/bin/Xvnc (InitExtensions+0x43) [0x44d9c3]
(EE) 21: /usr/bin/Xvnc (dix_main+0x210) [0x56ec30]
(EE) 22: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f9f9d7feb35]
(EE) 23: /usr/bin/Xvnc (0x400000+0x4b0fd) [0x44b0fd]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x7f9fa087dde0
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE)
```

I followed others who got the first part of the warning and made sure that the group "X Window System" was installed along with " pixman pixman-devel libXfont" packages that others said may be missing.

I am unsure where to go from here. I assume the segment fault originated with the fact the Xvnc is not starting but I seem to have exhausted the fixes that have worked for others.

Answer (score 0):

I never did find the solution to this problem. Eventually I gave up and installed x2go, which works well. So if you need to get VNC running, that seems to be the easiest solution.